# Android Flag display

Tags: android

I want to display flag of US and UK. On some devices flag shows up perfectly but on some text is shown as "US" and "UK" instead of flags. I have used unicode value as  and have also used below code but neither worked on device Samsung S4. Please help.

```
 int flagOffset = 0x1F1E6;
    int asciiOffset = 0x41;
    String country = language;
    int firstChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 0) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
    int secondChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 1) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
    String flag = new String(Character.toChars(firstChar))
            + new String(Character.toChars(secondChar));
    pFlagText.setText(flag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the unicode version supported on Samsung S4 is older than the one that the flags were added.

> The flag for the United States of America (USA), which may show as the letters US on some platforms.

Source: [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-united-states/)

## Possible solution

I'd recommend to just use drawables for the flags.

- [UK flag svg image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg) (from wikipedia)
- [US flag svg image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg) (from wikipedia)

Then you can use a converter from SVG to android drawable, like [this one](https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) [inloop.github.io]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Toast` or the `log console` to see what you get on S4 as the variable's value which is responsible for the flag and the names. Maybe there is a mismatch between this value and the flags' icon names. In this case you have to use conditional load of the image name based on the device.